# Custom endpoints of app not loading when APP_ENV is dev

Tags: shopware6

When I install an app while the `APP_ENV` is set to dev, custom endpoints, and script as a whole, do not get executed. When I install the same under prod it works, but developing like this is hell.

Am I missing something or could this be a bug? It worked under version 6.4.10.1

Comment: What is your current Shopware version?

Comment: Version 6.4.13.0

Comment: I found the problem: Shopware\Core\Framework\App\Lifecycle\Persister\ScriptPersister::refresh uses the relative app path, which is later used by Shopware\Core\Framework\App\Lifecycle\ScriptFileReader::getScriptPathsForApp. But this one works with the absolute path. Scripts are not found and in a later step every script is deleted from the database.

Comment: I made a pull request

Comment: Cool, can you post a link to the pull request.

Comment: Sure: https://github.com/shopware/platform/pull/2593

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has been fixed with commit on trunk, will be released with next version https://github.com/shopware/platform/commit/6cfd67921782e9d4d1387c542696b26573c5704f