# Shopware problem with app scripts in admin panel

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I'm trying to create a rule with app scripts but it's not working in the admin panel. If I activate the app via command line (bin/console app:activate MY_APP) then the rule gets created. But if I activate the app via the admin panel, nothing happens. What could be the problem?

```
{% do services.writer.upsert('rule', [
{
    name: 'mycustomrule',
    priority: 0,
    createdAt: "now"|date("Y/m/d H:i:s"),
    conditions: [{
        type: 'paymentMethod',
        value: {
            paymentMethodIds: [paymentMethodRepository.findByCashPayment().id],
            operator: '!='
        }
    }]
}
]) %}
```

Comment: Which Shopware version are you testing this with? Also you can try the following when you're in a `dev` environment:
In the network tab of your browser's dev-tools when you activate your app you should find a request to `/api/_action/extension/activate/app/YourAppName`. Inspect it and find the link to the Symfony Profiler as the value of the response header `X-Debug-Token-Link`. On that page there's a sidebar entry "Scripts". There it will show all the executed hooks as tabs. Your script should be listed under `app-activated`.

Comment: I'm using last Shopware version (I'm working on developer version and I have pulled the last version of shopware/platform in my project). I have URL with X-Debug-Token-Link, but under app-activated I don't have any hooks (No scripts called for this hook.).

Comment: I found a solution. The problem was with directory to scripts. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72886253/custom-endpoints-of-app-not-loading-when-app-env-is-dev